# Theorem-style numbering for tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I make a lot of diagrams and other illustrations in TikZ, and I've discovered a need to give them reference numbers - is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Normally you put them in figure environments and number those. If this does not apply to your documents, could you perhaps explain their structure more clearly?

Comment: @marmot I tried figure, briefly, but it made the actual tikzpicture disappear, so I didn't pursue it. Maybe I should try harder.

Comment: It does not make the picture disappear, but figures are by default floats, so they may get moved to another page. If a figure really disappears, you have either very strange settings, or the picture is too large, or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The float package allows to create new environments which can be numbered:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{Diagram}{htbp}{dia}

\begin{document}

\begin{Diagram}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{text}
\end{Diagram}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be just the thing - thanks.